# How to put form data in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just want that my form to return a contact object when I submit it to the back-end.
I tried to do it after the checks inputs.

So that I can subsequently on my side make a JSON Request containing a contact object.
Specification for my project: Returns the contact object
Thank you for your help.
I'm new to javascript!

```
 <form action="" method="post" class="row gy-4" id="formContact">
                    
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName">Firstname*</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="validFirstnameValue">
          <span class="error"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Lastname *</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="validelastNamevalue">
          <span class="error"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="email" class="form-label">Email *</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" value="validEmailValue">
            <span class="error"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="address" class="form-label">Adress *</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="" value="validAdressValue">
           <span class="error"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="city" class="form-label">City *</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="" value="validCityValue">
            <span class="error"></span>
       </div>

       <div class=" form-group my-4 text-center ">
            <button class="btn  btnSubmit fw-bold btn-secondary" id="submitButton" type="submit" value="envoyer">Commander</button>
       </div>

 </form>
```

```js
    let formContact = document.querySelector('#formContact');
    let inputFirstname = document.querySelector('#firstName');
    let inputLastname = document.querySelector('#lastName');
    let inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email');
    let inputAddress = document.querySelector('#address');
    let inputCity = document.querySelector('#city');



    const regexName = /^[a-zA-Z-\s]+$/;
    const regexMail = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[.]{1}[a-z]{2,10}$');
    const regexNumber = /^[0-9]{5}$/;
    const regexAdress = /^(([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+[\s\-]{1}[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+)){1,20}$/;



    document.querySelector('#formContact').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const borderCode = " #7EEA5E solid 2px"; 
        switch (e.target.id) {
            //TEST FIRSTNAME //
            case 'firstName':
                if (regexName.test(inputFirstname.value)) {
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    error = true;
                }
                break;
            // TEST LASTNAME //
            case 'lastName':
                if (regexName.test(inputLastname.value)) {
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    error = true;
                }
                break;
            // TEST EMAIL //
            case 'email':
                if (regexMail.test(inputEmail.value)) {
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    error = true;
                }
                break;
            // TEST ADDRESS //
            case 'address':
                if (regexAdress.test(inputAddress.value)) {
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    error = true;
                }
                break;
            // TEST CITY //
            case 'city':
                if (regexName.test(inputCity.value)) {
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    error = true;
                }
                break;
        }
        if (!error) {
            e.target.style.border = borderCode;

        }

    });

    document.querySelector('#submitButton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

        if (error) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Check');
        }


    });
    let contact = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        address: '',
        city: '',
    }
```

Comment: Can you please describe what are you trying to achive?

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed error generally means that you don't have backend endpoint/method to accept request

Comment: Off the back of @AidOnline01's comment - can you (a) share your backend code that handles these requests as a [mre], and (b) boil the frontend code you've shared here to a [mre] as well? We shouldn't have to wade through lines of unnecessary code to reproduce the issue you're experiencing. See [ask]

Comment: @esqew Sorry there was a problem when I uploaded my message.

Comment: @ninstudic Sorry, to what "*message*" are you referring? Where are you trying to upload something?

Comment: @AidOnline01 I want my form to return a contact object. I search my error.

Comment: @ninstudic, that's too unclear task. You are talking about localStorage, 405 error on your backend, and about form returning contact object. That's few unrelated tasks/problems. Please focus on what is the main problem, or try to edit your question so it will be clearer

Comment: @Aid, sorry , I change my title and description. Efficiency I was not clear.

Comment: There's probably no reason for that switch. HTML5 forms are very good at validating content. You can add the regex to the input pattern attribute. The form won't submit if the content isn't valid.

Comment: @ninstudic, please attach html form code

Comment: @ninstudic, I will make you an working example based on your form

Comment: @ninstudic, also paste valid values into input fields `value="validCityValue"`

Comment: @AidOnline01 Thank your for your help. So that I understand better. The objective of the project is also to code in javascript that's why I introduced the regex. Hoping that I will succeed in transforming my form into a contact object.

Comment: @AidOnline01 I added html form code.

Comment: @AidOnline01 Thanks for your help. My mistakes were not to declare a value on the inputs and therefore a bad declaration at the js level. In the future I will be more careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is crude working example based on your code

```js
// get elements
const formEl = document.getElementById('formContact');
const firstEl = document.getElementById('firstName');
const lastEl = document.getElementById('lastName');
const emailEl = document.getElementById('email');
const addressEl = document.getElementById('address');
const cityEl = document.getElementById('city');
const submitEl = document.getElementById('submitButton');


// regex
const regexName = /^[a-zA-Z-\s]+$/;
const regexMail = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[.]{1}[a-z]{2,10}$');
const regexNumber = /^[0-9]{5}$/;
const regexAdress = /^(([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+[\s\-]{1}[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+)){1,20}$/;

let error = false;

document.querySelector('#formContact').addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const borderSuccess = " #7EEA5E solid 2px"; 
  const borderError = 'red solid 2px';
  switch (e.target.id) {
      //TEST FIRSTNAME //
    case 'firstName':
      if (regexName.test(firstEl.value)) {
        error = false;
        e.target.style.border = borderSuccess;
      } else {
        error = true;
        e.target.style.border = borderError;
      }
      break;
      // TEST LASTNAME //
    case 'lastName':
      if (regexName.test(lastEl.value)) {
        error = false;
        e.target.style.border = borderSuccess;
      } else {
        error = true;
        e.target.style.border = borderError;
      }
      break;
      // TEST EMAIL //
    case 'email':
      if (regexMail.test(emailEl.value)) {
        error = false;
        e.target.style.border = borderSuccess;
      } else {
        error = true;
        e.target.style.border = borderError;
      }
      break;
      // TEST ADDRESS //
    case 'address':
      if (regexAdress.test(addressEl.value)) {
         error = false;
        e.target.style.border = borderSuccess;
      } else {
        error = true;
        e.target.style.border = borderError;
      }
      break;
      // TEST CITY //
    case 'city':
      if (regexName.test(cityEl.value)) {
         error = false;
        e.target.style.border = borderSuccess;
      } else {
        error = true;
        e.target.style.border = borderError;
      }
      break;
  }
});

formEl.onsubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
  if (error) {
    alert('Check');
    return;
  }

  let contact = {
    firstName: firstEl.value,
    lastName: lastEl.value,
    email: emailEl.value,
    address: addressEl.value,
    city: cityEl.value
  };
  
  console.log(contact);
};
```

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="row gy-4" id="formContact">
  <div class=" form-group">
    <label for="firstName">Firstname*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="John">
    <span class="error"></span>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Lastname *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="Smith">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email *</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" value="john@smith.com">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address" class="form-label">Adress *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="" value="Holy Mary street">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city" class="form-label">City *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="" value="New York">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>



  <div class=" form-group my-4 text-center ">
    <button class="btn  btnSubmit fw-bold btn-secondary" id="submitButton" type="submit" value="envoyer">Commander</button>
  </div>
</form>
```